# What is the best approach to upload a file using Jersey client?

Tags: java, file-upload, jersey, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I want to upload a file (a zip file to be specific) to a Jersey-backed REST server.

Basically there are two approaches (I mean using Jersey Client, otherwise one can use pure servlet API or various HTTP clients) to do this:

1)

```
 WebResource webResource = resource();
    final File fileToUpload = new File("D:/temp.zip");

    final FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    if (fileToUpload != null) {
        multiPart.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", fileToUpload, MediaType.valueOf("application/zip")));
    }

    final ClientResponse clientResp = webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(
        ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
    System.out.println("Response: " + clientResp.getClientResponseStatus());
```

2)

```
File fileName = new File("D:/temp.zip");
        InputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        String sContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName.getName() + "\"";
        ClientResponse response = resource().type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("Content-Disposition", sContentDisposition).post(ClientResponse.class, fileInStream);
        System.out.println("Response: " + response.getClientResponseStatus());
```

For sake of completeness here is the server part:

```
@POST
    @Path("/import")
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
    public void uploadFile(File theFile) throws PlatformManagerException, IOException {
        ...
    }
```

So I am wondering what is the difference between those two clients?
Which one to use and why?
Downside (for me) of using 1) approach is that it adds dependency on jersey-multipart.jar (which additionally adds dependency on mimepull.jar) so why would I want those two jars in my classpath if pure Jersey Client approach 2) works just as fine.
And maybe one general question is whether there is a better way to implement ZIP file upload, both client and server side...

Comment: did you find the answer to your question? I am in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 1 allows you to use multipart features, for example, uploading multiple files at the same time, or adding extra form to the POST.

In which case you can change the server side signature to:

```
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadMultipart(FormDataMultiPart multiPart) throws IOException {
}
```

I also found that I had to register the MultiPartFeature in my test client...

```
public FileUploadUnitTest extends JerseyTest {
@Before
    public void before() {
        // to support file upload as a test client
        client().register(MultiPartFeature.class); 
    }
}
```

And server

```
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
    public Application() {
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your question, it helped me write my jersey file unit test!